# Design a code to generate specific pattern

Tags: r, vector, dplyr

Is it possible to generate a column of sequence

```
1 1 2 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 .... so on
```

using `dplyr`

I tried with `lag()` function but did not get a clear idea

```
library(dplyr)
test <- as.data.frame(c(1:1000))
names(test) <- 'a'
# View(test)

test <- test %>% 
  mutate(
    c = # How to make this iterative to generate 1 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 .. so on
    b = ifelse(a %% c < a , a , NA)
  )

#tried to create 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 pattern
test <- test %>% 
  mutate(
    c = 1,
    c = ifelse(c <= lag(c),lag(c)+1,c)
  )
```

expected output is a column with sequence `1 1 2 1 2 3 1 2 3 4...so on`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
sequence(1:5)
# [1] 1 1 2 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 5
```

---

`sequence` is a wrapper around `lapply` and `seq_len`

```
function (nvec) unlist(lapply(nvec, seq_len))
```

Comment: its a cool answer. But I dont understand it. Isn't sequence supposed to mean numbers in a sequence?

Answer (score 2):

When using dplyr the length of the column should remain. 
instead, try this

```
#custom function
my.fun <- function (nvec) lapply(1:5, function(x) seq(1,x)) %>% unlist()

#test case with data frame with 12 rows
data.frame(a = 1:12) %>% 
  mutate(b = my.fun(a)[1:length(a)])
```

Comment: or `map(1:5, ~seq(1,.)) %>% flatten() %>% unlist()` if you want to go full tidyverse

Comment: @kresten thank you for your answer. it helped. my doubt is that if we already know the length of column (let us say number of rows are 12) so we want only 12 numbers the sequence should generate. i.e. 1 1 2 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 1 2. Isn't it possible by applying any logic on seq or sequence function in mutate condition